# How do I construct this json string and take its values in the action method? (scenario provided)

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9HDW.png)

In the image link above I have created a form which can dynamically add more rows of input fields

The values from the input field that are dynamically added are pushed into an array while the values on the green part are place into a javascript object.

```
reservations.push({ Day:d, Room: r, TimeIn: datetimeIn.toString(), TimeOut: datetimeOut.toString()});//this is assuming that only 1 row of input field was added

var r = JSON.stringify(reservations);
//There's only 1 course, description, section, datefrom and dateto while there can be many Day, Room, TimeIn, TimeOut.
var reservation = { CourseCode: courseCode.val(), Description: description.val(), Section: section.val(), DateFrom: dateF, DateTo: dateT, r };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ReserveSubject',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'reservation=' + JSON.stringify(reservation),
```

How do I take the values of the json string and create and instance of an object that will take those values

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReserveSubject(string reservation)
{
    Subject sub = new Subject();

    sub.CourseCode = reservation.CourseCode;
    sub.Description = reservationDescription;
    .
    .
    .
    //loop through reservation data from dynamically added rows of input field
    {
        Schedule sch = new Schedule();
        sch.Day = reservation.Day; 
        sch.Room = reservation.Room;
        .
        .
        .
        sub.Schedule.add(sch);
    }
        sub.ScheduleTable = MethodThatWillConvertScheduleListToDatatable(sub.Schedule);
}
```

Object to instantiate

```
public class Subject
{
    string CourseCode { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    string Section { get; set; }
    string DateFrom { get; set; }
    string DateTo { get; set; }
    List<Schedule> Schedule { get; set; }
    DataTable ScheduleTable { get; set; }
}

public class Schedule
{
    string Day { get; set; }
    string Room { get; set; }
    string TimeIn { get; set; }
    string Timeout { get; set; }
}
```

I have already downloaded NewtonSoft as i think most of your answer will make use of it.

Comment: This helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonObject = {
 "Prop1" : "something",
 "Prop2" : "something",
 "Prop3List" : GetSomeJsonScheduleList()
 etc...
};

public class ExampleModel 
{
    public string Prop1 {get; set;}
    public string Prop2 {get; set;}
    public IList<Schedule> Prop3List {get; set;}
}

public ActionResult ControllerMethod(ExampleModel model)
{
     //Use your model like normal
}
```

Then just JSON.stringify(jsonObject) in your ajax call.

Take note of the naming conventions.